# What's the meaning of Proctectable interface in JUnit source code?

Tags: junit, junit4

I'm recently digging into the source code of `JUnit-4.11`, what confuse me is that the seemingly  redundant `Protectable` interface. the declaration is as follows:

```
public interface Protectable {
    public abstract void protect() throws Throwable;
}
```

In the `TestResult` class, there is a `void run(final TestCase test)` method, in which a anonymous `Protectable` instance is realized as follows:

```
protected void run(final TestCase test) {
    startTest(test);
    Protectable p = new Protectable() {
        public void protect() throws Throwable {
           test.runBare();
        }
    };
    runProtected(test, p);

    endTest(test);
}
```

`runProtected` method is as follows:

```
public void runProtected(final Test test, Protectable p) {
    try {
        p.protect();
    } catch (AssertionFailedError e) {
       addFailure(test, e);
    } catch (ThreadDeath e) { // don't catch ThreadDeath by accident
        throw e;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        addError(test, e);
    }
}
```

As we can see, what `runProtected` does is just executing `test.runBare();`, so is there any sense to the existence of Protectable interface? Why can't we just write code like below.

```
protected void run(final TestCase test) {
    startTest(test);
    test.runBare();
    endTest(test);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your final question first, you can't use

```
protected void run(final TestCase test) {
    startTest(test);
    test.runBare();
    endTest(test);
}
```

because it won't do what you want. JUnit manages asserts using exceptions, specifically `AssertionFailedError`. So, `Assert.assertEquals()` throws an `AssertionFailedError` when the two values aren't equal. So, in the above method, the `endTest(test)` won't get called if there is an assertion failure, which means the correct events (failure/error of the test) won't get fired, and `tearDown()` won't get executed.

The `Protectable` interface is there to give a more generic interface to the runner, so that you don't have to hand a `TestCase` to the method, to allow different actions.

As an aside, this is part of the package `junit.framework.*`, which is JUnit 3. JUnit 4 is where it's at, and if you want to learn, look more in the `org.junit.*` packages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to handle thrown exceptions in specific way :
Call `addFailure` for assertion exception (your test failed), `addError` for other exception (your test is not well coded)

Answer (score 0):

This interface is to protect the TestCase by adding Throwable.
so junit could run any testcase safely.

```
The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language.
```